# ColdFusion Oracle Datasource Hangs After "Too Many" Rows

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion 10 on Windows, I have a datasource connected to Oracle 11g. I can submit a query as follows:

```
<cfquery name="qry_Test" datasource="dsn_orcl" maxrows="100">
  SELECT TRANSID FROM TBL_TRANS
</cfquery>
```

This will return my 100 rows of transaction IDs. But as I increase the number of columns in the query, the amount of rows I can successfully return goes down.

```
<cfquery name="qry_Test" datasource="dsn_orcl" maxrows="50">
  SELECT TRANSID, TRANSDATE FROM TBL_TRANS
</cfquery>
```

The maxrows=50 setting is arbitrary, but if I exceed a certain number, say 50, the page just hangs and hangs. So, as the query width increases, its depth decreases. Never seen this before.

Anybody ever experienced this?

Comment: I've seen it, but not with numbers that low.  It is possible to overwhelm a browser with too much data.  However, the last time I saw it was with Windows 95 and Netscape 3.  But getting to your query, why does it not have a where clause?

Comment: It's for demonstration only. I didn't discover it until I began limiting it using maxrows. I should mention I can run the same query with no problem on the same server using SQLPlus.

Comment: So, write the output to a file and you can trace whether it's server-side or client side. I assume you've tried more than one browser, and maybe more than one pc. Are you perhaps outputting a javascript that's becoming overloaded with too many rows? (Not that such a low number is itself too many, but if you have some poorly written script--*not saying that you do*), that could cause a browser hang. (Also while more than one browser might help, more than one pc is probably not going to change much, but if the error is client side, it's a consideration).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using  tag for limiting the number of rows returned you can try limiting it from the database side.
Try this code:-

```
<cfquery name="qry_Test" datasource="dsn_orcl">
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TRANSID, TRANSDATE 
FROM TBL_TRANS ORDER BY TRANSID) TB_TRANSACTION
WHERE rownum <= 50
ORDER BY rownum;
</cfquery>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: The trouble is, he should not be experiencing this error with such a low # and the tag solution "fixes" the problem more effectively than this. Instead, the purpose of his question is to discover *the source of the problem*

Comment: So for that he can debug that. without additional information nothing specific can be said regarding that. It can be from Coldfusion side or from the Database side. He can check by directly running the query in database. If it is working fine then in coldfusion or in jquery or in something else might be the problem.